# ROS2 Directory structure for using launch file with C++

Tags: ros2

When I have a C++ package I want to add a launch file to, where do I place the launch file exactly? Does it need to be in its own folder within the package folder or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The [official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html) and an [example package](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/a29e65623e8ace15b8253ab33f19f3d8165c3cfe/composition) can help you.

Comment: I followed https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Launch-system.html but it's not clear what the directory structure looks like for a C++ package. Could you explain it more? I have an existing package with source files and I want to add a launch file, what do I do?

Comment: Have you checked the example package provided in the first comment?